# Как в javafx прописать взаимодействие между Batton и TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии batton, программа использовала данные, введённые в TextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ. В коде Batton нужно создать переменную private TextField result (над этой строкой необходимо прописать @FXML), предварительно в файле sample.fxml, прописать fx:id="result" в строке <"TextField>, чтобы получилось <"TextField fx:id="result">
("result" - имя переменной).
Далее, в методе, отвечающим за выполнения кода Batton присвоить переменную "result" нужной переменной, например:

```
String str = String.valueOf(result.getText());
double a = Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(result.getText());
```